# Create number matrix in Java

Tags: java, loops, matrix

I'm trying to write a program that will prompt the user for a number between 1 and 9 and will create a matrix x by x where x is the number given. It should produce random numbers from 1 to x^2 to fill in the matrix. I have it worked out where, if I input '5' I get one row with 5 random digits and then four lines with just one number each. What am I missing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class MatrixFiller
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Getting input from the user
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Size of Matrix(a number between 1 and 9): ");
    int matrixn = input.nextInt();
    input.close();
    //max is the largest possible number that can be calculated
    //with the given number squared.
    int max = (matrixn * matrixn);
    //Counters for building the matrix
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    //Will create a line with x numbers on it but then produces
    //x lines with only one number. If given 5 it produces a
    //line with 5 numbers then four more lines with one number
    //each.
        do {
          do {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int mout = rand.nextInt(max - 0);
            System.out.print(mout + " ");
            i++;
          }
          while (i < matrixn);
          System.out.println();
          j++;
        }
        while (j < matrixn);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `i` at the beginning of the loop, otherwise it is still `matrixn` from the previous line.

```
do {
    i = 0;  // It won't work without this
    do {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int mout = rand.nextInt(max - 0);
        System.out.print(mout + " ");
        i++;
    } while (i < matrixn);
    System.out.println();
    j++;
} while (j < matrixn);
```

While this works, it would be much better to use `for` loops instead.

Comment: Thank you! I don't think we covered resetting loops. I was trying to find a way to send you a pm earlier on here lol but it's not featured :/

Comment: No problem. You should try to get used to using `for` loops. The code is `for (int i = 0; i < matrixn; i++) { ... }`. `i` starts from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The key is resetting that value of `i` to zero at the top of your first `do` loop.

Or you could use `for` loops as it seems cleaner for your purposes:

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (i=0; i<matrixn; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<matrixn; j++) {
        int mout = rand.nextInt(max);
        System.out.print(mout + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Does the random range need to be specified? int mout = rand.nextInt(max -min) ?

Comment: The range is defined to be `[0..max)` in the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)). I removed the `- 0` as it was redundant.

Answer (score -1):

Your Inner Loop only one time executed, **i** must be start from begging each time.

```
  do{
     i = 0 ;
     do {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int mout = rand.nextInt(max – 0);
        System.out.print(mout +  “ “);
        i ++;
     } while(i<matrixn);
     system.our.println();
     j++;
  } while(j < matrixn);
```